# join syntax in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I am using access,and I have two tables:

point:

```
id,x,y
1 32432432 143423232
2 32432443 143423300
```

line:

```
id startPoint endPoint
1  1          2
```

Now, when I query the line,I want the returned table will contain both the x,y of the startPoint and the endPoint.

I have tried the join:

```
select line.*,point.x as x1,point.y as y1 from line as line join point as point on line.startPoint=point.id where line.id=1;
```

Then I can get the following result which only contain the startPoint.

```
id startPoint endPoint x1 y1
1  1          2        ......
```

Then how to retrive the endPoint while I want the result like this(x2 y2 is the coordinate of the endPoint):

```
id startPoint endPoint x1 y1 x2 y2
1  1          2        ......
```

I tried two `join`,but it does not work.

```
select line.*,point1.x as x1,point1.y as y1,point2.x as x2,point.y as y2 from line as line left join point1 as point on line.startPoint=point1.id  left join point as point2 on line.endPoint=point2.id where line.id=1;
```

Comment: I do not have an answer for you, but I will provide a comment from my Braile keyboard. MS Access join syntax made me dig my eyes out with a spoon.

Comment: me too,however we have to use it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Access has weird syntax rules for multiple joins. You have to put them in parentheses like so.

```
select line.*, point1.x as x1,point1.y as y1,
    point2.x as x2, point.y as y2
from (line as line
left join point as point1
on line.startPoint = point1.id)
left join point as point2
on line.endPoint = point2.id
where line.id = 1;
```

Each additional join requires another left paren before the first table and a right paren after the second-to-last join.

Comment: works,thank you.BTW,can you suggest me some SQL syntax articles?

Comment: @hguser: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb259125%28v=office.12%29.aspx)